# Find Active Directory Groups for a specific location

Tags: active-directory, groups

I am a system admin for a site that I inherited from a previous admin. I am currently trying to determine what AD Groups are associated with this site (access to servers, other resources) so I can do some cleanup.

Is there a way to find out what groups are associated with this location\Which groups have access to my servers?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nope.  ​  ​  ​  ​  ​  ​  ​  ​  ​  ​

Comment: I was able to search for groups associated with this location by the building code. I also found what file shares are controlled by what group on my servers using Varonis.